# Why is my $templateCache setup not working with new Angular router?

Tags: angularjs

I cannot understand why my $templateCache setup is not working...

See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7nhIwvhQmNNWsdpPHrhd?p=preview). I used it with the [new Angular router](https://angular.github.io/router/), where I have my `home` component template in the $templateCache. The app.js file looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngNewRouter','app.home']);

app.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('components/home/home.html', '<h2>The home page</h2>{{home.test}}');
}]);

app.controller('AppController', ['$router','$templateCache', AppController]);

function AppController($router,$templateCache) {
  var vm = this;
  console.log("The template looks like this:",$templateCache.get('components/home/home.html'));
  $router.config([{
    path: '/',
    component: 'home'
  }]);

}
```

My components/home/home.js file:

```
angular.module('app.home', [])
  .controller('HomeController', [HomeController]);

function HomeController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = "String from the home controller";
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
http://run.plnkr.co/OFd5k46BCkBdnfkK/components/home/home.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note you're registering it in the cache as a relative, not an absolute url.

Comment: Yes, as I want to. Should I register it as an absolute url for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `ngNewRouter`, and it seems that it uses some convention-over-configuration approach in looking up a template (I don't see anywhere else where the template URL is specified), but if you look closely at the error message, it says:

> Failed to load template: `./components/home/home.html` (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

(Notice the preceding `./`) So, change the cache key accordingly:

```
$templateCache.put('./components/home/home.html', '<h2>The home page</h2>{{home.test}}');
```

**EDIT:**

And, in fact, the [documentation of `ngNewRouter`](https://angular.github.io/router/$componentLoaderProvider) does specify the default (i.e. conventional) behavior:

> The default behavior is to dasherize and serve from `./components`. A component called `myWidget` uses a controller named `MyWidgetController` and a template loaded from `./components/my-widget/my-widget.html`.

Comment: Great! Thanks Dude (or Dudess)! Who knew that a small dot and a slash would make such a vital difference in programming :D